# Hibernate "PreInsertEvent.getSource()" NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

I'm recieving the following error when trying to do inserts:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : org.hibernate.event.PreInsertEvent.getSource()Lorg/hibernate/event/EventSource;

I've seen [other](http://drglennn.blogspot.com/2008/10/hibernate-preinserteventgetsource.html) people with the same problem due to incompatibility in hibernate jars, but I believe I've got it right (according to the [compatibility matrix](https://www.hibernate.org/6.html#A3))

Here's the relevant section from my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can anyone advise?

Regards

Marty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, but I'm not sure it's correct -- anyone with a better, please advise:

Added a reference to cglib, and explicity excluded hibernate (was including 3.2)

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I am not using Maven, but I added all the latest dependencies by hand and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug : https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HVAL-81 . It occurs when you reference an older version of hibernate validator than core.

Comment: This is just a duplicate, look in the original bug [HVAL-75](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HVAL-75) for more information/status.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem for me when this error occurred is

1. Hibernate-core dependency was not in my EAR packaging.
2. By default it was picking the jboss.4.2.3/.../lib's hibernate3.jar.
3. Just adding hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA to my dependencies list in EAR
   packaging.
4. Already had the overriding of loaders set in jboss-app.xml.
5. Excluded the hibernate-core from hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA
   (don't think this is required as the core supplied will be 3.3.0.SP1
   and will be omitted anyhow).

It worked with some exclusions of some already existing xml-apis, ejb3-persistence, etc. dependecies from the hibernate-core.

Finally the core dependency looked like this.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

*Note: I don't think cglib is required is its not relevant to this context.*

Hope this is useful for someone.