# Hibernate does not working in Maven web application in Glassfish 4.1.2

Tags: hibernate, maven, glassfish

I have a Maven web application and it is published in glassfish 4.1.2.
But I can not insert, change, delete, and querying using Criteria.
It gives the following error:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.event.PreUpdateEvent.getSource()Lorg/hibernate/event/EventSource;
```

I already followed some examples on the internet and I did not succeed

can anybody help me?

below my dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>                  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Show your **pom.xml**.

Comment: Do you really need to use Hibernate artifacts which are so old? You are using a version of **hibernate-core** [that is over 9 years old](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA). If you [use a recent version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core), then [you won't even need hibernate-entitymanager](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager): _"deprecated - use hibernate-core instead"_. However, if you have no choice about those versions, please provide a more complete stack trace.

Comment: Unfortunelly yes. I am migrating the projects to maven, then migrate the versions of hibernate, jsf, java, etc.

Comment: OK, understood. In that case, you might look at this very old SO post: [Hibernate “PreInsertEvent.getSource()” NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/882338/2985643)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using these dependencies below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0.SP1</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0.SP1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
<artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>antlr</groupId>
<artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
<version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```